# combine the i:th matrix from N lists

Tags: r, list, matrix, apply

I would like to combine large rectangular matrices stored in multiple lists. E.g. `rbind.fill.matrix {plyr}` the i:th matrix from all `N` lists. The number of matrices `n` within each list is equal across `N` lists.

```
#Dummy data using N=2, n=2

 # binary matrices
 ls1 <- replicate(n=2, list(matrix(rbinom(1,0.5,n=20), nrow=2)))
 ls2 <- replicate(n=2, list(matrix(rbinom(1,0.5,n=12), nrow=2)))

 ls1 <- lapply(ls1, "colnames<-", head(LETTERS,ncol(ls1[[1]])))
 ls1 <- lapply(ls1, "rownames<-", 1:2)

 # create some overlap
 ls2 <- lapply(ls2, "colnames<-", c("A","E",tail(LETTERS,ncol(ls2[[1]])-2)))
 ls2 <- lapply(ls2, "rownames<-", 1:2)
```

The result would be similar to `rbind.fill.matrix(ls1[[1]], ls2[[1]])` for all `N` lists and `n` matrices.

I tried something like this, which obviously does not do it. What it does is to combine each matrix within each list.

```
lsNames <- c("ls1", "ls2")

sapply( lsNames, function(x) do.call(rbind.fill.matrix, get(x)))
```

Any pointers would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ls1 and ls2 have equal length:

```
lapply( seq_along(ls1), function(i) {
  rbind.fill.matrix(ls1[[i]], ls2[[i]])
} )
```

Result:

```
# [[1]]
#      A  B  C  D E  F  G  H  I  J  W  X  Y  Z
# [1,] 0  1  1  0 0  0  0  1  1  0 NA NA NA NA
# [2,] 0  1  1  0 0  1  1  0  0  0 NA NA NA NA
# [3,] 0 NA NA NA 0 NA NA NA NA NA  0  0  1  1
# [4,] 0 NA NA NA 0 NA NA NA NA NA  1  1  1  0
# 
# [[2]]
#      A  B  C  D E  F  G  H  I  J  W  X  Y  Z
# [1,] 1  1  1  0 1  1  0  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA
# [2,] 1  1  1  0 0  0  0  1  1  0 NA NA NA NA
# [3,] 0 NA NA NA 0 NA NA NA NA NA  1  0  0  1
# [4,] 0 NA NA NA 0 NA NA NA NA NA  0  1  1  1
```

#### For multiple lists

```
# create list of lists:
list_of_lists <- list(ls1, ls2)

lapply( seq_along(list_of_lists[[1]]), function(i) {
  arg_lists <- lapply(list_of_lists, function(l) l[[i]])  
  rbind.fill.matrix(arg_lists)
} )
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Although, might not be so handy when `N` lists is large...